# Missing HTML content when using selenium to scrape webpage

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape the reduced price of a product from a website.

The HTML looks like this when inspecting the website:

[image: HTML from Inspector]

My code looks like this:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/chromedriver.exe') 
browser.get('https://www.mydays.de/magicbox/kurzurlaub')
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
Price = soup.find('div',{"class":"c-mbvoucher__pricebox"})
```

But my Result looks like this:

```
<div class="c-mbvoucher__pricebox">
<span class="c-mbvoucher__price">159 €</span>
<span class="c-mbvoucher__person">
            für 2 Personen        </span>
</div>
```

Why is some information missing in my result?

I also tried find_all, but the above is the only one matching.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To extract the text **159 €** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.c-mbvoucher__pricebox>span.c-mbvoucher__price"))
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='c-mbvoucher__pricebox']/span[@class='c-mbvoucher__price']"))
  ```

Ideally, to locate the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.c-mbvoucher__pricebox>span.c-mbvoucher__price"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='c-mbvoucher__pricebox']/span[@class='c-mbvoucher__price']"))).text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  159 €
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update

If your usecase is to extract the text ***119,25 €*** as the text is within a *Text Node* you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.c-mbvoucher__pricebox")))).strip())
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='c-mbvoucher__pricebox']")))).strip())
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  119,25 €
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I may have formulated my question wrong, i`m trying to extract the offer-price (see screenshot - 119,25 € ). That price wont occur in my result - only the 159€ - which is the original price.

Comment: @LukasZimmermann Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.